# SQL Where clause condition causes Column not found error

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I'm having trouble with what should seemingly be a fairly straightforward SQL query.  The code below:

```
    SELECT lines.ItemID, lines.TransCode, lines.Qty, headers.InvoiceID, items.ItemID, items.Description, items.Misc2, items.Misc3, items.Location
    FROM InvLines lines 
    JOIN InvHeaders headers ON lines.ParentRecordID = headers.RecordID 
    JOIN Items items ON lines.ItemID = items.ItemID
    WHERE headers.CustomerID = "LOST" AND headers.InvoiceID NOT LIKE "K%" AND lines.TransCode <> "T";
```

Causes the error message:
    ASA Error -143: Column 'LOST' not found [SQL State=52003, DB Errorcode=207]

Obviously "LOST" is the condition I am selecting for, so I don't understand why it is getting treated as a column.  I can't seem to find any information on this error caused by a similar situation.

I'm using SQLWorkbench/J to connect to the db and make this query.

Apologies for any necessary information left out or poor formatting, I am new at this.  Please let me know and I will correct it.

Comment: Strings must be enclosed in single quotes, double quotes indicate object names in Standard SQL: `WHERE headers.CustomerID = 'LOST' AND headers.InvoiceID NOT LIKE 'K%' AND lines.TransCode <> 'T'`

Comment: Thank you, I just discovered that.  Previously single quotes hadn't worked because apparently the text editor I had copied/pasted the query over from had changed them to back ticks, so I had thought I needed double quotes. A forehead slapper.

Comment: Irony!! Column 'LOST' not found. It wouldn't be called LOST :)